# Twitter4j Exception with track and geolocation

Tags: twitter, twitter4j

I am trying to get tweets with either the word "python" in it or the ones that are around my city

This is my code:

```
    StatusListener listener = new MyStatusListener(twitter);
    twitterStream.addListener(listener);
    FilterQuery query = new FilterQuery();

    String[] arr = { "python" };
    double lat = 18.5203;
    double lon = 73.8567;
    double[][] locations = { { lat, lon } }; // for Pune city

    query.track(arr);
    query.locations(locations);

    twitterStream.filter(query);
```

When I run this I get following exception:

```
Returned by the Streaming API when one or more of the parameters are not suitable for the resource. The track parameter, for example, would throw this error if:
 The track keyword is too long or too short.
 The bounding box specified is invalid.
 No predicates defined for filtered resource, for example, neither track nor follow parameter defined.
 Follow userid cannot be read.
Location track items must be given as pairs of comma separated lat/longs: [Ljava.lang.String;@405ef8c2

[Thu Jun 26 19:06:58 GMT+05:30 2014]Parameter not accepted with the role. 406:Returned by the Search API when an invalid format is specified in the request.
Returned by the Streaming API when one or more of the parameters are not suitable for the resource. The track parameter, for example, would throw this error if:
 The track keyword is too long or too short.
 The bounding box specified is invalid.
 No predicates defined for filtered resource, for example, neither track nor follow parameter defined.
 Follow userid cannot be read.
Location track items must be given as pairs of comma separated lat/longs: [Ljava.lang.String;@405ef8c2
```

I get the same message in pair. If I remove the locations condition, the code works fine. I am not sure what the issue is here. Can someone help please?

Answer (score 0):

That was my bad. I was assuming that if I dont provide a pair, twitter will assume a radius (like it does on web UI- near a city). But I guess you have to provide a bounding box. Giving a bounding box worked for me.